# can't create simple image from php exec , can create with the same command as standalone

Tags: php, linux, imagemagick

I have this code running in CentOS 5.5 ,PHP 5.1.6 ,Apache/2.2.3 ,ImageMagick 6.2.8

```
$convert = "/usr/bin/convert";
$command = "$convert -size 100x100 xc:blue mytest.jpg";
$test_image = exec($command);
echo "<img src=\"mytest.jpg\">";
```

when i run the php tester i dont get the image created , only the echo string printed on page as html.
but when i run the same command as onliner the image does created just fine.

```
/usr/bin/convert -size 100x100 xc:blue mytest.jpg
```

what is wrong here i can't tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PHP assumes that the web server has permissions to execute programs and to write to the current directory. You should use [`popen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php) to send the image to stdout and either use the [`data:` scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) to embed the image data into the HTML, or put the PHP script as the `src` for the `img` tag and output the appropriate header and then the image data.

Comment: the image doesn't created before the html

Comment: the convert -size 100x100 xc:blue mytest.jpg from php 
dont create the image mytest.jpg

Comment: hi i did .. and it was working .. but now its stooped to work.
i have no idea way .

Comment: ok now i can't even create simple file in the directory , and the directory has all permissions , does it netter if im using root account ?

Answer (score 0):

Does PHP, the user, have permission to do that?